# social login - how to use variables outside of function in react?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I try to use social login.

if I success to login in kakao. they give me access_token and I use it to mutation to my server

below is my code

```
import { useMutation } from "react-apollo-hooks";
import { KAKAO_LOGIN } from "./AuthQuery";


export default () => {
  const kakaoLoginMutation = useMutation(KAKAO_LOGIN, {
    variables: { provder: "kakao", accessToken: authObj.access_token },
  });

  const kakaoLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.Kakao.Auth.login({
      success: function (authObj) {
        console.log(authObj.access_token);
      },
    });
  };
  if (authObj.access_token !== "") {
    kakaoLoginMutation();
  }
  return (
    <a href="#" onClick={kakaoLogin}>
      <h1>카카오로그인</h1>
    </a>
  );
};
```

if I success to login using by function kakaoLogin, it give authObj.
console.log(authObj.access_token) show me access_token

and I want to use it to useMutation. but it show to me authObj is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a local state to hold `authObj`

```
const [authObj, setAuthObj] = useState({});

const kakaoLogin = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.Kakao.Auth.login({
    success: function(authObj) {
      setAuthObj(authObj);
    },
  });
};

const kakaoLoginMutation = useMutation(KAKAO_LOGIN, {
  variables: {
    provder: "kakao",
    accessToken: authObj.access_token
  },
});

if (authObj.access_token !== "") {
  kakaoLoginMutation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Apollo auth docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header) (you read it, right?) you **should know tokens should be sent using headers**.

... if auth link is used and **reads the token from localStorage** ... then **any login function (mutation, request) result should end storing token in localStorage** (to be passed by header in next queries/mutations) ... it should be obvious.

### In this case

... we have a bit different situation - kakao token is passed into login mutation as variable ...

**We can simply, directly** (not using state, effect, rerenderings) **pass the kakao token to 'mutation caller'** (`kakaoLoginMutation`):

```
// mutation definition
const [kakaoLoginMutation] = useMutation(KAKAO_LOGIN);
// event handler
const kakaoLogin = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.Kakao.Auth.login({
    success: function(authObj) {
      // run mutation
      kakaoLoginMutation({ 
        variables: {
          provder: "kakao",
          accessToken: authObj.access_token
        }
      })
    },
  });
};
```

**When required, login mutation (`KAKAO_LOGIN`) result can be processed within `onCompleted` handler**:

```
const [kakaoLoginMutation] = useMutation(KAKAO_LOGIN, 
  onCompleted = (data) => {
    // save mutation result in localStorage
    // set some state to force rerendering
    // or redirection
  }
);
```